# Dual boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 14.04/15.04 making windows boot by default?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I've seen tons of topics about this but i couldn't find anything that answers to my question:

How can I install Ubuntu with UEFI enabled BUT making windows boot by default without showing GRUB and if i want to boot Ubuntu I press the F12 key (in my case) before booting to boot ubuntu?

Explaining: I have an Acer aspire E5-511 with windows 8.1 pre installed, then i updated to windows 10, now i'd like to install ubuntu but I don't want GRUB to show up when i want to boot windows i want windows to boot normally without it, but make it that Ubuntu boots directly from the boot selection menu pressing F12 and selecting it's partition.

As far as i know, I must create a "/" partition, a swap partition and an EFI partition in Fat32, but i don't know where to install the GRUB loader, in /dev/sda? or /dev/sda5 (efi partition)? or /dev/sda6 (ubuntu partition)? to make it show up ONLY when i select it from boot menu.

Boot Process by default:
Power button > boot windows normally

Boot process to boot ubuntu: Power button > Press F12 > Boot selection menu > select Ubuntu/GRUB partition > boot Ubuntu ( without or with)

I don't know if you understood what i want to do :P

***EDIT:*** I'm running UEFI. I can't disable it, for some reason if I disable UEFI and Fast boot Windows won't boot then, I get a black screen with "Couldn't find booteable HDD" instead, so i must install Ubuntu in UEFI mode in order to dual boot with windows.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** Are you running UEFI or BIOS boot? (If you don't know, boot an Ubuntu LiveDVD, choose `Try Ubuntu`, run `gparted` and post a screen shot of that.)  [Edit] your answer to reflect this additional information and then drop me a note @Fabby.

Comment: @Fabby done! hope this helps

Comment: Yes, it does, and *unfortunately* that also makes your question **off-topic here as what you're asking is an UEFI solution outside of Ubuntu.**  You need to read your UEFI manual to have Windows boot as default (and unfortunately just like the BIOS: they're all different...)

Comment: I'm sorry...  **:-(**

Comment: Actually, there are solutions entirely within Ubuntu -- see my answer, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm running dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.04 on UEFI mode either. I don't have to create any partitions or do something as you present. By default, after you install Ubuntu, your first boot option on BIOS would be Ubuntu Grub. So that's why you boot into Ubuntu Grub.

All you have to do is go to BIOS (press F2 or F12), move to Boot section and make Windows Boot Manager to be the first boot option. Then save changes (or press F10) and you'll see the result.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

To do precisely what you want, you need to edit your EFI's boot order. You can do this in Ubuntu with the `efibootmgr` utility. First, type `sudo efibootmgr` to see the boot list, or add `-v` to include more detail. This will show something like this:

```
$ sudo efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0007,0003,0001
Boot0000* rEFInd (direct)   ACPI(a0341d0,0)PCI(1f,2)03120a00010000000000HD(2,1f4800,82000,5f6b4992-fcfe-4a2c-9e67-98b0a30dfe7d)File(\EFI\refind\refind_x64.efi)
Boot0001* Lenovo Recovery System    HD(3,276800,1f4000,de3b7563-97f5-48c6-ab7f-2f5d6d57c644)File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\LrsBootMgr.efi)RC
Boot0003* ubuntu    HD(2,1f4800,82000,5f6b4992-fcfe-4a2c-9e67-98b0a30dfe7d)File(\EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi)RC
Boot0007* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,1f4800,82000,5f6b4992-fcfe-4a2c-9e67-98b0a30dfe7d)File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}....................
```

That's a slightly truncated example from one of my computers. Pay attention to the `BootOrder` line. Each number matches one of the subsequent `Boot####` entries. In my case, `Boot0000` (`rEFInd (direct)`) is first; but yours is likely to show an `ubuntu` entry as being first, and `Windows Boot Manager` later. You want to reverse those two, which you can do by specifying a new `BootOrder` with the `-o` option to `efibootmgr`:

```
sudo efibootmgr -o 0007,0003,0000,0001
```

This example, if I were to type it on my computer, would adjust the order so that the Windows boot loader was first, followed by GRUB (`ubuntu`), rEFInd, and finally the `Lenovo Recovery System`. Your numbers will be different. Indeed, your entries will be different; you may see fewer or more entries than I've shown here. Entries for booting whole disks (either in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode or via fallback boot loaders), PXE-booting from network devices, booting optical discs, and so on are all common. It's easier to parse all this if you omit the `-v` from the initial `efibootmgr` command; but sometimes the short descriptions are deceptive, so you may want to include `-v` so you can check the filenames associated with boot entries.

All that said, personally I wouldn't do it this way. I'd use [GRUB Customizer,](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1664134) or more likely options for rEFInd, which I maintain and prefer, to set Windows as the default entry. This is because most computers aren't very reliable at detecting those keypresses to enter the boot manager. They also vary from one system to another, which can be very frustrating if you own several computers and can't quite remember whether it's F8, F12, Enter, or something else you must press to get to the built-in boot manager.

Answer (score 0):

1.OpenTerminal in Ubuntu

2.Sudo gedit /etc/default/grub

A text file will be open

3*.Change
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
to
GRUB_DEFAULT=4

Save the text file

4.sudo update-grub

5.Restart System